# Store NSNumber in a long double type

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, types, nsnumber

I have a number stored in an `NSNumber` which I would like to put into a `long double`, like so:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; 

[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 

[f setMinimumSignificantDigits:5];

NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"1.1234567899"]; 

long double lnumber = mynumber;
NSLog(@"%Lf ",lnumber);
```

Answer (score 10):

An [`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/) is an Objective-C object, and `long double` is a primitive type. You can't assign an object to a primitive-typed variable. If you want the numerical value that is stored in the `NSNumber`, you need to use one of its methods to retrieve it:

```
long double lnumber = [myNumber doubleValue];
```

There is no provision for storing a `long double` in an `NSNumber`; the largest floating-point type is simply `double`. It seems that `long double` may be the same size as `double` on iOS anyways: see this [Apple Support Forum thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/9334648?messageID=9334648).

As [ThomasW mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488956/store-nsnumber-in-a-long-double-type/6489036#6489036), [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDecimalNumber), a fixed-point number class, offers both more precision (up to 38 digits) and accuracy than `NSNumber`. There is still no way to get a `long double` out of it, though; you would have to do all your math only with `NSDecimalNumber`s to retain the precision.

Your question title originally mentioned `NSInteger` as well, although the body didn't, so let me add this note. An [`NSInteger`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16) is a primitive type, like `long double`, so you can in fact assign from one to the other.

```
NSInteger myInteger = 10000;
long double lnumer = myInteger;
```

However, because it is an integer, it can't have a fractional part.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the best you are going to get is a double value.

```
long double lnumber = [mynumber doubleValue];
```

You can also do this if the value is in a string to begin with

```
NSString* sval = @"1.1234567";
double dval = [sval doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't. As [NSNumber Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says, `NSNumber` supports `double` and `float` but not `long double`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need high precision you could use `NSDecimalNumber`, but it doesn't support `long double` either.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -3):

Try to cast the number:

```
long double lnumber = (long double) mynumber;
```

Comment: Your comment made my day :))))) You're awesome :D